# SharePoint not loading properly just showing sprite images - SP 2013

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage

I'm having a problem in a site collection where it just load the images attached but when i click on a sub-site it works fine.
No idea why this happening.

Thanks in Advance

[image]

Comment: Is there any custom masterpage applied? or have you changed the custom look?

Comment: Hi Pradip thanks for the reply and its a custom masterpage.
its got an html and a master file.
its says you can only edit the html and not the masterpage.
But when you make changes to the html does this replicate the master file?

Comment: Yes. Master file is associated with html file. So you can only update HTML file only to have those changes on masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

Check the browser compatibility. Most often these problems are related to Internet Browsers and arises because of the Internet Brower incompatibility. Mostly the problem occurs with `IE11`. Try to view the site in `Chrome or Firefox` and post your results. Also you can check if you are running `IE 32-bit` version and not 64-bit as this could also be a problem.

---

Also this can be caused by the CU updates and patch. Please try updating the farm with the SharePoint Foundation Update of the November 2014 CU (KB2899508)